# How can I configure application insights for service fabric application?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I could not find any SDK from azure application insights for service fabric on nuget site. Does any one know how to configure it properly?

The following link appears to be out of date:

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-application-insights-setup.md

Thanks.
Raghu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that article and the referenced NuGet package are obsolete. The Service Fabric and App Insights teams are collaborating on a better integrated solution that will provide 1st class support for SF concepts. No concrete timelines yet but work is ongoing.

Comment: Please do post back when there is some news on that front. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanMcKenna - any further news?

Comment: We'll post back when we have news. There isn't anything yet and still do not have a timeline. If you want to use Application Insights within your application, downloading their SDK **should** work, but this doesn't integrate directly with Service Fabric. The recommended approach for instrumentation is still to use EventSource and upload your events to Azure Diagnostics or EventHub

Comment: What is the recommended solution for a SF solution when you dont use Azure eg local and AWS ?